# Persist ember model with embedded record

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have the following ember models:

```
App.Location = DS.Model.extend({
    street: DS.attr('string'),
    city: DS.attr('string'),
    area: DS.attr('string'),
    lat: DS.attr('string'),
    lng: DS.attr('string'),
    report: DS.belongsTo('report', {embedded: 'always'})
});

App.Report = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    reg_num: DS.attr('string'),
    location_str: DS.attr('string'),
    location: DS.belongsTo('location', {embedded: 'always'})
});
```

In `App.ReportController` when I try to save the report I also want to embed the location object in the request payload. So far I tried the following code:

```
App.ReportController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        saveReport: function(record) {
            var self = this,
                report = this.get('model'),
                location = this.store.createRecord('location', {
                               lat: this.get('lat'),
                               lng: this.get('lng')
                           });
                report.set('location', location);
                report.save().then(function (result) {
                    self.transitionToRoute('list');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

However in the request payload location is always `location: null`.

How to add `location` to the request payload?

Comment: What version of ember-data and what serializer do you use?

Comment: DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'am missing something, but I know two different ways of handling embedded records (ember-data >= 1.0.0-beta):

1. [Rewriting DS.Adapter's methods](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration): serialize/extract*/normalize and others, - to set JSON payload in a way which Ember can work with.
2. Using [DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html) for configuring DS.Serializer.

I can assume you get `location: null` because of [default DS.Serializer's behavior with serializing relationships](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships): Ember expects `id` value in `belongTo` property and list of ids in `hasMany` property. `LocationModel` doesn't have an id after creating and before saving into server database. When default serializer tries to form an outgoing json payload while saving `ReportModel` with attached newly created `LocationModel`, it gets id of `LocationModel` (`null`) and puts that id in `location` property.

Comment: Thanks, I had to rewrite the DS.JSONSerializer and to use the DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin configuration to get this working. I'll post the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Putting composite JavaScript objects in the payload shouldn't be rocket science, I hope there is a less complicated way to achieve this.

Make sure that you don't have `belongsTo` defined for both relations because you will end up with stack overflow:

```
App.Location = DS.Model.extend({
    street: DS.attr('string'),
    city: DS.attr('string'),
    area: DS.attr('string'),
    lat: DS.attr('string'),
    lng: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Report = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    reg_num: DS.attr('string'),
    location_str: DS.attr('string'),
    location: DS.belongsTo('location', {embedded: 'always'})
});
```

I had to configure the PostSerializer and override the serializeBelongsTo to make this work

```
App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        location: {embedded: 'always'},
        report: {embedded: 'always'}
    }
});

DS.JSONSerializer.reopen({
    serializeBelongsTo: function(record, json, relationship) {
        var key = relationship.key,
            belongsToRecord = Ember.get(record, key);

        if (relationship.options.embedded === 'always') {
            json[key] = belongsToRecord.serialize();
        } else {
            return this._super(record, json, relationship);
        }
    }
});
```